# unresolved reference when using pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

Recently, I want to use python do some image processing. I choose [programming computer vision with python](http://programmingcomputervision.com/) to begin. Following is a code example in this book:

```
from PIL import Image
from pylab import *

im = array(Image.open('bird.jpg').convert('L'))

figure()

gray()

contour(im, origin='image')
axis('equal')
axis('off')
```

I have imported `pylab`, when I run it in pychar, all commands like array, figure, gray, contour, and axis tell me `unresolved reference`.

When I run it in terminal of ubuntu: python .py
it said that `name 'array' is not defined.`

Can anyone help me figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I find a way to solve it, but it seems a little stupid:

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = array(Image.open('bird.jpg').convert('L'))

print im.shape, im.dtype

plt.figure(1)
plt.gray()
plt.contour(im, origin='image')
plt.figure(2)
plt.hist(im.flatten(), 128)
plt.show()
```

I just import `numpy` and `matplotlib` respectively. I know it is not convenient as `pylab`, but at least it works for me now. 
whish better answer!

Comment: `numpy` and `pyplot` will keep your namespace tidy... avoid `pylab`... and `import numpy` (as `np` if you like), but not `numpy *`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque yeah, this also help me familiar with functions in respective package. thanks